# Can you dynamically add an event listener to variables in a for loop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to dynamically add an eventlistener to a group of li tags that will toggle a CSS class

```js
const item = $('#dynamic-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

const strikeOut = () => this.classList = this.classList.toggle('strike-out');

const addClass = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    let link = item[i];
    link.onclick = strikeOut;
  }
}

addClass();
```

```css
.strike-item {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dynamic-list" style="list-style: none;">
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have a feeling that I'm not assigning the strikeout function correctly to each link however I'm open to all suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Some problems to fix:

- jQuery collections don't have a `getElementsByTagName` function. No need for jQuery, just use a plain `querySelectorAll`
- Arrow functions do not capture their calling context - rather, they inherit the calling context of their surrounding block. Use a standard function instead so that the `this` inside `strikeOut` refers to the clicked element
- Your CSS refers to `strike-item`, but your JS toggles a class name of `strike-out`.

After fixing:

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll('#dynamic-list li');

const strikeOut = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('strike-item');
}

const addClass = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    let link = item[i];
    link.onclick = strikeOut;
  }
}

addClass();
```

```css
.strike-item {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dynamic-list" style="list-style: none;">
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

But you might consider using event delegation instead, that way you only add *one* listener rather than a listener for every `li`:

```js
document.querySelector('#dynamic-list')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const { target } = e;
    if (!target.matches('li.dynamic-item')) return;
    target.classList.toggle('strike-item');
  });
```

```css
.strike-item {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dynamic-list" style="list-style: none;">
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many things going wrong here, `getElementsByTagName` is not a jquery selector its a javascript selector. Here is an example how to toggle :

```js
const item = $('#dynamic-list li');

const strikeOut = (e) =>{ 
  $(e.target).toggleClass('strike-item')
}

const addClass = function() {
    for( let i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
        let link = item[i];
        link.onclick = strikeOut;
    }
}

addClass();
```

```css
.strike-item {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dynamic-list" style="list-style: none;">
 <li class="dynamic-item">Item 1</li>
 <li class="dynamic-item">Item 2</li>
 <li class="dynamic-item">Item 3</li>
 <li class="dynamic-item">Item 4</li>
 <li class="dynamic-item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Try Simple Code here**

```js
function myAction(me){
  me.classList.toggle('strike-out');
}
```

```css
.dynamic-item.strike-out {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dynamic-list" style="list-style: none;">
  <li class="dynamic-item" onClick="myAction(this)">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item" onClick="myAction(this)">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item" onClick="myAction(this)">Item 3</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item" onClick="myAction(this)">Item 4</li>
  <li class="dynamic-item" onClick="myAction(this)">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```